# book synopsis api from google or amazon?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-api, google-books

If I use amazon or google book, for example
[http://www.amazon.com/The-Inca-Trail-Trailblazer-Trekking/dp/1873756291](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1873756291)  or

http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rLwNAAAACAAJ&dq=isbn:1873756291&hl=&source=gbs_api

Both return the same book synopsis(Rediscovered just earlier this ...), however, if I use amazon api or google book api, this information is not returned.

google book api example:
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:1873756291

Is there a way to retrieve this from either google or amazon using their api call?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only speak for Amazon, but no - this doesn't seem to be possible with their API. The API you need is the Product Advertising API; http://associates.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html

The operation would be 'ItemLookup' and the response group would be 'ItemAttributes', but I'm afraid the result set doesn't include a synopsis.

Answer (score 5):

So, I can now speak for Google too! :)

This is a public Google Books API call for 'Freakonomics';
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/wNPnl5zYA-cC

You will see that they do return a synopsis, the 'description'.

Comment: You can also search very easily. For example, by ISBN:

`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9780439554930`

Comment: Thanks a ton! The thing to do here seems to be:
1. Get book data from Google API
2. Retrieve Amazon's URL (if you want the link for your app) via ItemLookup