# How can I get book descriptions from the Amazon Selling Partner API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-selling-partner-api

I have been developing a Software that gathers information from de [Amazon SP-API](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/what-is-the-selling-partner-api) - more specifically, the [Catalog Items API](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/catalog-items-api-v2022-04-01-reference). With most products, it works well, but when it comes to books, the "product_description" attribute has a null value, even though you can see it if you access the website.

Does anybody know a way to get the description displayed in the web?
I have tried different books and even different locales, and all seem to have the same issue. Here is an example:

For [Anne Of Green Gables](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/055321313X) I used https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/catalog/2022-04-01/items/055321313X?marketplaceIds=ATVPDKIKX0DER&includedData=attributes,dimensions,identifiers,images,productTypes,relationships,summaries as my endpoint, and it returned the following JSON:

```
{
    "asin": "055321313X",
    "attributes": {
        "item_name": [
            {
                "Value": "Anne of Green Gables"
            }
        ],
        "product_description": null,
        "bullet_point": [
            {
                "Value": "8 complete oooks in boxset."
            }
        ],
        "color": [
            {
                "language_tag": "en_US",
                "standardized_values": null,
                "value": "Multicolor",
                "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
            }
        ],
        "size": null,
        "list_price": [
            {
                "currency": "USD",
                "value": 5.99
            }
        ]
    },
    "dimensions": [
        {
            "marketplace_id": null,
            "item": {
                "width": {
                    "Unit": "inches",
                    "Value": 0.87
                },
                "length": {
                    "Unit": "inches",
                    "Value": 4.13
                },
                "height": {
                    "Unit": "inches",
                    "Value": 6.88
                },
                "weight": {
                    "Unit": "pounds",
                    "Value": 0.3747858454
                }
            },
            "package": {
                "width": {
                    "Unit": "inches",
                    "Value": 4.1338582635
                },
                "length": {
                    "Unit": "inches",
                    "Value": 6.8503936938
                },
                "height": {
                    "Unit": "inches",
                    "Value": 0.8661417314
                },
                "weight": {
                    "Unit": "pounds",
                    "Value": 0.3968320716
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "images": [
        {
            "marketplaceId": "ATVPDKIKX0DER",
            "images": [
                {
                    "variant": "MAIN",
                    "link": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51QmhihxkZL.jpg",
                    "height": 500,
                    "width": 301
                },
                {
                    "variant": "MAIN",
                    "link": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51QmhihxkZL._SL75_.jpg",
                    "height": 75,
                    "width": 45
                },
                {
                    "variant": "MAIN",
                    "link": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71rtzg36RAL.jpg",
                    "height": 1008,
                    "width": 607
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "relationships": [
        {
            "marketplaceId": "ATVPDKIKX0DER",
            "relationships": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a case through the Amazon Seller Central web, and they replied to me a few days ago saying that the attribute synopsis is not available for fetching by using the SP-API. I have now come across [an old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186477/book-synopsis-api-from-google-or-amazon) that I hadn't found before, where it is also shared a similar issue with the same conclussion.